# Insert Function not execute in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create insert function in postgresql when this function execute for data insert that time error generate and display message in screen this function `does not exit`. What problem in data insert in query?

My Insert Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertuserlogin(userloginidp integer, usercategoryidf integer, usertypeidf integer, usertypereferenceidf integer, loginname character varying, loginpassword character varying, menutypeidf integer, username character varying, dashboardconfig text, careprovideridf integer, isactive boolean)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$BEGIN
 INSERT INTO "tbuserlogin" VALUES (userloginidp,usercategoryidf,usertypeidf,usertypereferenceidf,loginname,loginpassword,menutypeidf,username,dashboardconfig,careprovideridf,isactive);
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION insertuserlogin(integer, integer, integer, integer, character varying, character varying, integer, character varying, text, integer, boolean)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Insert Query

```
SELECT insertuserlogin(1,2,4,3,'fg','sdf',6,'err','fgsd',7);
```

Error Message

```
function insertuserlogin(integer, integer, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT insertuserlogin(1,2,4,3,'fg','sdf',6,'err','fgsd',7);
           ^
```

HINT:  `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

How can i add explicit type casts in this function in postgresql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your original function has 11 arguments while

`SELECT insertuserlogin(1,2,4,3,'fg','sdf',6,'err','fgsd',7);`

has only 10. Looks like you forgot to set `isactive` (to be true or false)
Try:

```
`SELECT insertuserlogin(1,2,4,3,'fg','sdf',6,'err','fgsd',7,'t');
```

Comment: replace `character varying` with `text` in your function definition